# update array of object with multiple condition in mongoose failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
[{
  "date": "18/12/2010",
  "babies": [{
    "id":1,
    "name": "James",
    "age": 8,
  }, {
    "id":2,
    "name": "John",
    "age": 4,
  }]
}]
```

I want to set the age of John to 10 but failed. I have to do multi condition to be more specified.

```
Babies.update({"date":date, 'babies.id': 1}, {'$set': {age:10}, function(err, response){
        res.json(response);
  })
```

The first condition is date and the second condition is the array of object of babies, which in this case it's the id. Above query has no error and no effect, where did I do wrong?

I debug with doing this query

```
Babies.find({'babies.id': 1}, function(err, response){
        res.json(response);
  })
```

and it couldn't find the correct target, maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `{'$set': {'babies.$.age':10}}` instead of `{'$set': {age:10}}`.

```
Babies.update({"date":date, 'babies.id': 1},
   {'$set': {
      'babies.$.age':10
      }
  },
 function(err, response){
    res.json(response);
 })
```

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

Refer to [MongoDB Positional Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) for more information.

Comment: It worked! thanks. but what if my date is an array? I want to update data base on multiple dates.

Comment: @JamieAnderson : See [MongoDB $in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing only object of field value {age:10} in $set flag, Pass the value in format of Array.index.field. So it would become like this -

```
{ $set: { 'babies.$.age': 10 } }
```